# How to Keep user logged in react native using Asyncstorage even if i close the App?

Tags: react-native

How to keep user logged in Using AsyncStorage in react native without redux? if you have any source code please provide it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?])(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 2):

In app.js

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    LoginPage: {screen : LoginPageContainer, navigationOptions: { header: null } },
    MiddlePage: {screen : MiddlePageContainerIndex, navigationOptions: { header: null } }
  }
);
```

In login page

```
import { getItem } from '../../api/getItem';

componentDidMount = async() => {


        let dataToken = await getItem();
 
        //if token is available redirect to middlepage
        if(dataToken !== null) { 

            const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

            navigate('MiddlePage');
        }

    }
```

In getItem.js

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export const getItem = async() => {

    try {

        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_token');

        if( value !== null ) {
           
            return JSON.parse(value);

        }else {
            return null;
        }
        

   } catch (error) {

       console.log(error);
       return null;
   }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First Of All store your data to the local storage like below code

`await AsyncStorage.setItem('login', True');`

and after closing the app. whenever user open app again check the local storage for login like below code

```
  const login = await AsyncStorage.getItem('login');
    if (login !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      // navigate to the home or any other screen 
    }
   else{
       // navigate to the Login screen or any other screen 
}
```

For mode details AsyncStorage details check this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html)